# Chrome gets stuck when trying to debug with VSCode

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, xdebug, moodle

I am a Moodle developer using UTM for my Moodle container (Moodle 4.1.1, Postgres (Debian 12.13-1.pgdg110+1)).

After the recent update of Google Chrome (version 116.0.5845.187 (arm64)) VSCode (version 1.82.0) seems to cause Chrome to get stuck when accessing my container via `http://localhost:58000/`.

I'm accessing my container in VSCode via SSH and use the Xdebug helper in Chrome for debugging.

Do you have any idea why Chrome gets stuck and what I could try to get it to work again?

I tried different containers but the problem persisted.

Comment: Not sure what UTM stands for, but does Chrome get stuck when Xdebug is disabled too? Either when Xdebug helper doesn’t start the debugger or if XDEBUG_MODE doesn’t include “debug”?

Comment: I have a new container with Moodle 4.2 now, with which the problem does not occur anymore. But I think you are right that it was most probably an XDEBUG issue.